# How to determine tab width(in pixels) for non-monospace font?

Tags: text-rendering

I'm developing a text renderer library which is similar to *FreeType* for my game. I don't know how to determine the tab width.

When I'm handling **control characters**, I found a problem, that is my text renderer is not only for monospace fonts but also for **non-monospace fonts**. I know that for monospace fonts, the width of the tab aligning can be 4 or 8 spaces, depending on the usage of the text renderer (***AFAIK***, most of the programming IDEs intend tabs to 4 spaces; and for creating tables, the software often intend tabs to 8 spaces). But for non-monospace fonts, which value should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After watching lots of IDE's behavior of handling non-monospace fonts, I found the answer:

Use the width of **space character ('\x20')** as the unit of the tab width, and the tab width should be **4 spaces** by default.

Also I gave a choice for the users to determine how to **align characters** for non-monospace fonts, one is to **align characters normally** as we see how other programs (such as Microsoft Word, Chrome, etc.) align non-monospace font text, the other one is to **force aligning** characters as monospace style by fix the width value of each characters, and the fixed width value were determined by scan all of the alphabets, digits and punctuations, and find a maximum value for it. And for **full-width** characters, I just let the width value x 2.